# Segfault when assigning to char* in struct

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

So I have a struct "sequence" that has a char* in it.  When I try and create a sequence, whenever I try and change the char* it segfaults.  Here is the related code.  The struct:

```
typedef struct _sequence {
  unsigned int length;
  unsigned char* bytes;
} Sequence;
```

The constructor:

```
Sequence* newSequence(unsigned char firstByte) {      //Creates new  sequence, allocates memory
  printf("Creating new Sequence\n");
  Sequence* seq = (Sequence*)malloc(sizeof(Sequence));
  printf("Have new sequence\n");
  seq->length = 1;
  printf("Set length\n");
  seq->bytes[0] = firstByte;
  printf("Set variables\n");
  return seq;
}
```

Now I have a main function here just for testing purposes, this file will in the end not have a main function.  But here is what i used to testing:

```
int main() {
  char test[] = "ab";
  printf("Testing sequences!\n");
  Sequence* newSeq = newSequence(test[0]);
  printf("Made new sequence!\n");
  outputSequence(newSeq, stdout);
  printf(" <-- new Sequence created\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The printfs are again for testing purposes.  It always prints out all the way up to "Set length\n" in the constructor, then segfaults.  What am I doing wrong?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sequence* seq = malloc (sizeof(Sequence));
```

Here you allocate memory space for one char * , and one int, but you need to allocate space for what you want to store on what is pointed at by your char *, this way :

```
seq->bytes = malloc (my_string_size);
```

Only then can you start storing characters in your allocated chunk of memory.

Edit : for instance, to store one single character, you could do :

```
seq->bytes = malloc(1);
seq->bytes[0] = firstByte;
```

to use it as a single character. But the good habit in C to manipulate string is to always leave one char more, in that fashion :

```
seq->bytes = malloc(2);
seq->bytes[0] = firstByte;
seq->bytes[1] = '\0';
```

The 2nd method looks more like a real 'string' in C.

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was thinking was wrong, but was unsure.  Thank you for explaining it so well.  I'll check off the answer once the minimum time has passed.

Answer (score 3):

You allocated apace for the structure correctly, but you didn't allocate any space for the buffer pointed to by the `bytes` element.

This line invokes undefined behavior because `bytes` is uninitialized:

```
seq->bytes[0] = firstByte;
```

You need to *also* allocate a buffer and point `seq->bytes` to it.

Comment: or define seq->bytes as a fixed length array of char